# viserjs Chart coming unwanted count number 01

Tags: css, reactjs, bizcharts, viser

Im using my react project for **[viserjs chart](https://viserjs.github.io/demo.html#/viser/pie/sex-distribution-of-short-video-users-in-the-first-quarter-of-2018)** , i have some conflict i find to remove count 1 text, no way to find that count label, anyone know how to hide or remove

Thanks.

[image: Image description here]

here the code

```
import { Chart, Tooltip, Facet } from 'viser-react';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as React from 'react';

const data = [{
  type: '男性',
  value: 56.4
}, {
  type: '女性',
  value: 43.6
}];

const eachView = function (view, facet) {
  var data = facet.data;
  var color = void 0;
  if (data[0].type === '男性') {
    color = '#0a9afe';
  } else {
    color = '#f0657d';
  }
  data.push({
    type: '其他',
    value: 100 - data[0].value
  });
  view.source(data);
  view.coord('theta', {
    radius: 0.8,
    innerRadius: 0.5
  });
  view.intervalStack().position('value').color('type', [color, '#eceef1']).opacity(1);
  view.guide().html({
    position: ['50%', '50%'],
    html: '<div class="g2-guide-html"><p class="title">' + data[0].type + '</p><p class="value">' + (data[0].value + '%') + '</p></div>'
  });
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setStyle();
  }

  setStyle = () => {
    const id = 'legend-html';
    if (document.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    const styleTxt = `
      .g2-guide-html {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          vertical-align: middle;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 1.5
      }

      .g2-guide-html .title {
          font-size: 12px;
          color: #8c8c8c;
          font-weight: 300;
      }

      .g2-guide-html .value {
          font-size: 18px;
          color: #000;
          font-weight: bold;
      }
    `;
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('id', id);
    style.innerHTML = styleTxt;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Chart forceFit data={data} height={400} padding='auto'>
        <Tooltip />
        <Facet 
          type="rect"
          fields={['type']}
          padding={20}
          showTitle={false}
          eachView={eachView}
        />
      </Chart>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
showTitle={false}

 <Tooltip showTitle={false}/>
```